# Searching multiple keywords in SP2010

Tags: search, search-results

I can do a plain search against a property "Skills" with one keyword. Like "Engineer" and search works. However, if I do a search "engineer and driller" then it doesn't bring anything? Am I doing something wrong and need additional configuration in order for this to work.

A person may have multiple skills and we need to able to search that person otherwise the search results too long for one keyword. I hope I am making sense.

Comment: How are you entering the multiple skills per person in the property?
What syntax are you using for the search?

Comment: seperated by comma enclosed in double quote

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try:

```
Skills:engineer Skills:driller
```

If you only want both:

```
Skills:engineer AND Skills:driller
```